# How do I pass the name of a function as a parameter then reference that function later?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to pass the name of a function "testMath" as a string into a wrapper function called "runTest" as a parameter.  Then inside 'runTest' I would call the function that was passed.  The reason I'm doing this is because we have a set of generic data that will populate into variables regardless of the test, then a specific test can be called, based on whatever the user wants to test. I am trying to do this using javascript/jquery.  In reality the function is much more complex including some ajax calls, but this scenario highlights the basic challenge.

```
//This is the wrapper that will trigger all the tests to be ran
function performMytests(){
     runTest("testMath");    //This is the area that I'm not sure is possible
     runTest("someOtherTestFunction");
     runTest("someOtherTestFunctionA");
     runTest("someOtherTestFunctionB");
}


//This is the reusable function that will load generic data and call the function 
function runTest(myFunction){
    var testQuery = "ABC";
    var testResult = "EFG";
    myFunction(testQuery, testResult); //This is the area that I'm not sure is possible
}


//each project will have unique tests that they can configure using the standardized data
function testMath(strTestA, strTestB){
     //perform some test
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need the function names as string? If not, you can just pass the function like this:

```
runTheTest(yourFunction);


function runTheTest(f)
{
  f();
}
```

Otherwise, you can call

```
window[f]();
```

This works, because everything in the 'global' scope is actually part of the window object.

Answer (score 2):

Inside runTests, use something like this:

```
window[functionName]();
```

Make sure `testMath` in the global scope, though.

Answer (score 1):

I preffer to use apply/call approach when passing params:

```
...
myFunction.call(this, testQuery, testResult); 
...
```

More info [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx).

Comment: I can see where this could be much cleaner, but unfortunately apply wouldn't work in my scenario.